# Not able to communicate through websocket from amazon connect

Tags: javascript, angular, aws-sdk, amazon-connect

I'm integration amazon connect platform to maintain a two-way flow communication in our own chatbot where customer will be the user in our platform and agents will be there on amazon connect platform to communicate. I'm using websockets for the communication now but it is giving me Forbidden error. Details are mentioned below

Initially, I have used **aws-sdk** and **@aws-sdk/client-connectparticipant** library to make the connection with aws and then multiple SDKs in order are used further to send the messages.

1. startChatContact -> Used AWS library to make the connection with AWS and then using it to retrieve participation token
2. createParticipantConnection -> Using participation token to retrieve connection token from this sdk using **Type: [ 'CONNECTION_CREDENTIALS' ]**
3. sendEvent -> Using connection token and ContentType: 'application/vnd.amazonaws.connect.event.connection.acknowledged' to send the event
4. sendMessage -> After sending the event, sending the message with connection token and ContentType: 'text/plain'

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import * as AWSConnectParticipant from "@aws-sdk/client-connectparticipant";

private messageText = "";
private connectionToken = "";

private connectParticipant = new AWSConnectParticipant.ConnectParticipant({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: '...',
    secretAccessKey: '...'
  },
  region: '...'
});

// It will get called when user sends a message on the chat window
public sendMessage(text: string): void {
  this.messageText = text || "";

  if (this.connectionToken) {
    this.sendEventOnAWSConnect();
  } else {
    this.startChatContact();
  }
}


startChatContact() {
  const connect = new AWS.Connect({
    accessKeyId: '...',
    secretAccessKey: '...',
    region: '...'
  });

  const params = {
    ContactFlowId: '...',
    InstanceId: '...',
    ParticipantDetails: {
      DisplayName: 'Customer'
    }
  };

  connect.startChatContact(params, (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      this.createParticipantConnection(data);
    }
  });
}

createParticipantConnection(startChatContactRes: any) {
  const params = {
    ParticipantToken: startChatContactRes.ParticipantToken,
    Type: [ 'CONNECTION_CREDENTIALS' ]
  };

  this.connectParticipant.createParticipantConnection(params, (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      this.connectionToken = data.ConnectionCredentials.ConnectionToken;
      this.sendEventOnAWSConnect();
      this.checkAgentMessage(data.Websocket.Url);
    }
  });
}
  
sendEventOnAWSConnect() {
  const params = {
    ConnectionToken: this.connectionToken,
    ContentType: 'application/vnd.amazonaws.connect.event.connection.acknowledged'
  };

  this.connectParticipant.sendEvent(params, (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      this.sendMessageOnAWSConnect();
    }
  });
}

sendMessageOnAWSConnect() {
  const params = {
    ConnectionToken: this.connectionToken,
    Content: this.messageText,
    ContentType: 'text/plain'
  };

  this.connectParticipant.sendMessage(params, (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      console.log("Agent connected");
    }
  });
}
```

It is working fine as expected. I'm able to send messages on amazon connection with the following code. But I'm facing some issues on receiving agent messages back. I have search for any events which I can trigger on my end or any webhook, but unable to find anything on the same.

**Issue on 1st method: Not a good approach. Looking for a better solution** 
So, I have used polling technique initally where I have used **getTranscript** SDK from @aws-sdk/client-connectparticipant and calling the api on every 2 seconds to check for any new agent messages but I'm looking for a better method now on the same.

**Issue on 2nd method: getting connect.core.getWebSocketManager() as undefined**
After exploring, I have also found that there is an **onMessage** event, which I can trigger using **amazon-connect-streams** and **amazon-connect-chatjs** library after creating agent session but
**connect.core.getWebSocketManager()** as undefined. Also, code after connect.contact is not getting executed, so I have commented that also. I have also created customer session similarly but there also **onMessage **event is not getting triggered. I'm calling its method i.e. checkAgentMessage after I get response from createParticipantConnection method successfully since I'm using contact id, participant id and participant token in checkAgentMessage method, which I'm getting from createParticipantConnection method. Below is the code.

```
import "amazon-connect-streams";
import "amazon-connect-chatjs";

createParticipantConnection(startChatContactRes: any) {
  const params = {
    ParticipantToken: startChatContactRes.ParticipantToken,
    Type: [ 'CONNECTION_CREDENTIALS' ]
  };

  this.connectParticipant.createParticipantConnection(params, (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      this.connectionToken = data.ConnectionCredentials.ConnectionToken;
      this.sendEventOnAWSConnect();
      this.checkAgentMessage(data);
    }
  });
}

checkAgentMessage(startChatContactRes: any): void {
// for type customer
// const customerChatSession = connect.ChatSession.create({
  //   chatDetails: {
  //     contactId: startChatContactRes.ContactId,
  //     participantId: startChatContactRes.ParticipantId,
  //     participantToken: startChatContactRes.ParticipantToken,
  //   },
  //   type: connect.ChatSession.SessionTypes.CUSTOMER
  // });

  // for type agent
  // connect.contact(contact => {
    // if (contact.getType() !== connect.ContactType.CHAT) {
    //   // applies only to CHAT contacts
    //   return;
    // }
    
    // alternative: if you want control over the args of `connect.ChatSession.setGlobalConfig()` and `connect.ChatSession.create()`
    // contact.onAccepted(() => {    

      const agentChatSession = connect.ChatSession.create({
        chatDetails: {
          contactId: startChatContactRes.ContactId,
          participantId: startChatContactRes.ParticipantId,
          participantToken: startChatContactRes.ParticipantToken,
        },
        options: { // REQUIRED
          region: "...", // REQUIRED, must match the value provided to `connect.core.initCCP()`
        },
        type: connect.ChatSession.SessionTypes.AGENT, // REQUIRED
        websocketManager: connect.core.getWebSocketManager() // REQUIRED
      })

      agentChatSession.onMessage(event => {
        console.log("event", event);
      });
  // });
// });
}
```

I have checked if I can set connect.core.getWebSocketManager() from somewhere, but got nothing help on the same.

**Issue on 3rd method: getting Forbidden as error or message**
I have also come across another solution and that is from web sockets. So, I'm implementing the same but there I'm getting error as **Forbidden**

I have changed my **createParticipantConnection** function with something as below:

```
createParticipantConnection(startChatContactRes: any) {
  const params = {
    ParticipantToken: startChatContactRes.ParticipantToken,
    Type: [ 'WEBSOCKET' ]
  };

  this.connectParticipant.createParticipantConnection(params, (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (data) {

      let socket = new WebSocket(data.Websocket.Url);

      socket.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("[open] Connection established");
        console.log("Sending to server");
        socket.send("My name is John");
      };

      socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log("event", event);
        console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
      };

      socket.onclose = function(event) {
        if (event.wasClean) {
          console.log(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`);
        } else {
          // e.g. server process killed or network down
          // event.code is usually 1006 in this case
          console.log('[close] Connection died');
        }
      };

      socket.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log(`[error]`);
      };

      // this.connectionToken = data.ConnectionCredentials.ConnectionToken;
      // this.sendEventOnAWSConnect();
      // this.checkAgentMessage(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Changed Type from **CONNECTION_CREDENTIALS** to **WEBSOCKET** to retrieve the websocket url. Getting output on the same as:

[open] Connection established
Sending to server
event MessageEvent {...}
[message] Data received from server: {"message": "Forbidden", "connectionId":"...", "requestId":"..."}

It is throwing Forbidden as error or message. Please let me know if there is anything I have left which needs to be also implemented or I have done anything wrong here. Also please let me know, if anybody have the solution for the issue on 2nd method or if there is any other method to retrieve agent messages as well.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `CreateParticipantConnection`, you need to send a subscribe message. You'll then start receiving messages & events on the websocket.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_CreateParticipantConnection.html :

> For chat, you need to publish the following on the established websocket connection:
>
> {"topic":"aws/subscribe","content":{"topics":["aws/chat"]}}